# Determine $a_1$ by substituting the bessel function into the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

> For positive n, the ordinary differential equation
>
> $$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'+\left(1-\dfrac{n^2}{x^2}\right)y=0$$
>
> has as a solution the Bessel function of order n, $J_n\left(x\right)=x^n\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_kx^k$
>
> Determine $a_1$ by substituting the series for the Bessel function into the differential equation.

So I have $y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{k+r}$ , $y'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(k+r)x^{k+r-1}$ and $y''(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(k+r)(k+r-1)x^{k+r-2}$

So subbing in I get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(k+r)(k+r-1)x^{k+r-2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(k+r)x^{k+r-2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{k+r-2}=0$$

Then I get:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k((k+r)(k+r-1)+(k+r)+1)x^{k+r-2}+[a_0(r(r-1)+r+1)x^{r-2}]+[a_1((r+1)r+(r+1)+1)x^{r-1}$$

I am unsure where to go from here

Comment: It looks like you did not properly account for the $1 - \frac{n^2}{x^2}$ term when you did the substitution.

Comment: @xidgel sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant that when you substitute back into the original differential equation, you need to multiply the $y$ term by $(1-\frac{n^2}{x^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

You should get for the coefficients of the power $x^{k+r}$ the equation
$$
[(k+r+1)(k+r+2)+(k+r+2)-n^2]a_{k+2}+a_k=0.
$$
Together with the "shortened" equation for the lowest orders this gives
$$
[r^2-n^2]a_{0}=0,\\
[(r+1)^2-n^2]a_{1}=0,\\
[(k+r+2)^2-n^2]a_{k+2}+a_k=0.
$$
(Or only the last equation for $k=-2,-1,0,1,...$ with $a_k=0$ for $k<0$.) Now note that $r=n$ was given, so that $a_1=0$ and
$$
a_{k+2}=-\frac1{(k+2)(k+2+2n)}a_k
$$
for $k\ge 0$.